# FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Timed - out

Tags: wordpress

my WordPress site for FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Timed - out suddenly, what to do now? I m a newbie in coding......suddenly, what to do now?
Thank you all for your kind help!

Comment: my website:https://www.feelings-inc.com

Answer (score 0):

Just to close the question, i have settled this by SHOPIFY.
Yar dun try using tech stuff too much time if u are not a tech nerd but trying to learn. Its meaning...less, anyways SHOPIFY handled that.
one more thing in the world I know from the pandemic.
dun believe in self learn mysteries , for those un tech new bies, I m also,
just try to get money solve the problems, nobody have the time to help u out even they are seems nice kind tech ppl becox they are busy earning money.
So finally solution - > difficult tech problem, -> shopify(money) ->earn money.